# Oracle Apex One region slide over the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm currently using Oracle APEX 5.1. In my page, I have an interactive grid and a region which slides in and out on the click of a button. But when the region slides in, it has to slide over the grid and cover it partially and slide out uncovering the grid. Is this possible in APEX? How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also consider the page template "Right Side Column"

The menu will squish the page, not cover it, so it's not quite what you're after, but it's declarative.

What you describe is within the realms of a webpage, so APEX could do it.
Heck, I did something similar here before the era of UT, and with jQuery.slide() you could make it, err, slide out, instead of appear.
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=73000:1::::::

Answer (score 0):

How about a modal window? Create a region whose template is "Inline Dialog". Here's a walkthrough: https://community.oracle.com/blogs/rodrigomesquita/2016/07/04/oracle-apex-5-modal-window-with-universal-theme

Comment: Modal window will open on the grid. So yes this will partially satisfy what I was asking for. But I want the region to slide from the right onto the grid. Is that possible?